# Reading hyperlink URL

Tags: php, phpexcel

How do I read the URL of a hyperlink within a cell using PHPExcel?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$url = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E26')->getHyperlink()->getUrl();
```

**EDIT**

you might want to test whether the cell has a hyperlink first

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E26')->hasHyperlink();
```

**EDIT 2**

Note that hyperlinks are not loaded when setReadDataOnly(true)

Comment: This only returns an empty string. Is there more to the story? Is there a special loading option required? I'm using PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5

Comment: This should return the URL, unless you loaded the file with setReadDataOnly(true). Note that PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5 only reads hyperlinks from BIFF8 files (MS Excel 98 and above), not from BIFF5 files (MS Excel 95)

Comment: Problem solved, I did have setReadDataOnly set to true, didn't know it would stop me from reading hyperlinks. If you edit your answer to include that I'll vote it up. Thanks!

Comment: I have an issue. If a cell contains url like http://test.com/index.html#4, $cell->getHyperlink()->getUrl() will give me sheet://4, instead of an url. Any idea?

Comment: @kenpeter - please learn how to post questions on StackOverflow.... in most cases, asking your question as a comment to an answer to somebody else's question, especially one as old as this, is unlikely even to be noticed... I've seen your question on the PHPExcel board, and am investigating; but it's likely to be a bug in PHPExcel